# systemd `systemctl stop` aggressively kills subprocesses

Tags: redhat, systemd, systemctl

I've a daemon-like process that starts two subprocesses (and one of the subprocesses starts ~10 others).  When I `systemctl stop` my process the child subprocesses appear to be 'aggressively' killed by `systemctl` - which doesn't give my process a chance to clean up.

How do I get `systemctl stop` to quit the aggressive kill and thus to allow my process to orchestrate an orderly clean up?

I tried `timeoutSec=30` to no avail.

Comment: Have you reviewed the docs in `man systemd.services` and `man systemd.kill` ?

Answer (score 17):

[`KillMode=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html#KillMode=) defaults to `control-group`. That means every process of your service is killed with SIGTERM.

You have two options:

- Handle SIGTERM in each of your processes and shutdown within `TimeoutStopSec` ([which defaults to 90 seconds](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html#DefaultTimeoutStartSec=))
- If you really want to delegate the shutdown from your main process, set `KillMode=mixed`. SIGTERM will be sent to the main process only. Then again shutdown within `TimeoutStopSec`. If you do not shutdown within `TimeoutStopSec`, systemd will send `SIGKILL` to all your processes.

**Note**: I suggest to use `KillMode=mixed` in option 2 instead of `KillMode=process`, as the latter would send the final `SIGKILL` only to your main process, which means your sub-processes would not be killed if they've locked up.

Comment: that's is opposite. the user.services default to `mixed`, which kills right away. what the question wanted was `killMode=control-group` but they were inheriting the bad default from his user.slice. That's why the timeout was being ignored. enjoy the longer explanation on

Answer (score 3):

A late (possible) answer, but as I googled for weeks with a similar issue, finding nothing, I figured I add my solution. 
My error was that I ran the systemd unit as root and switched (using sudo) to "the correct" user in the startscript (inherited from SysVinit script).
That starts the processes in the user.slice which is killed mercilessly on shutdown. When I changed the unit file to run as the correct user (USER=myuser) and removed sudo from the start script, the processes start in the system.slice and get properly handled on shutdown.